# Windows Server 2016 Enable Installer Logging

Tags: windows, windows-installer, windows-server-2016

On a newly installed Windows Server 2016, I need to fully enable Windows Installer Login. All the current documentation available references the registry location:
    "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer"

This path is not present in the WS 2016 server and I can't seem to find anything else on the subject or what to do when it is not present.

Has anyone run into this, and if so, what is the correct location for WS2016, or, how do you work around it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the key if it doesn't exist.

Comment: That did it. Thanks.